# how to identify an uninstall attempt which fails due to app defined as device admin

Tags: android, uninstallation, device-admin

when attempting to uninstall an app which is defined as device admin, the uninstall fails (this is normal system behavior); however, there is no notification to explain to the user why this happens.

is there a way to identify the uninstall attempt  so i can handle this?

parsing logcat (as root) is doable; e.g. on my device i get from `PackageManager` logcat:

`Not removing package`*`package name`*`: has active device admin`

but, besides requiring root, this might be android-version-specific

Answer (score 0):

First off, at least on Android 9 I do get a system notification when trying to uninstall an app with device admin, telling me that the app could not be uninstalled because it is a device admin.

Apart from that I do not really see a way to solve this (apart from the one you already described). There are of course the broadcasts `PACKAGE_REMOVED` / `PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED` but those are only triggered after the package has been *successfully* removed.

Maybe if you could desribe *why* you want to handle the uninstall attempt yourself I could think of other ways to address your issue.

Comment: BBB: i want to handle this precisely because there is no message (as of 4.4.x). regarding `PACKAGE_REMOVED`: "The package that is being removed does _not_ receive this Intent." (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand it right, but there can't be a message that the package was not removed if the uninstall failed. User has to remove device admin first, for this event there is another broadcast.

Comment: BBB: the package will not receive `PACKAGE_REMOVED` regardless of anything. ever. device admin has nothing to do with this. see above the quote from the official docs. the problem is that the user tries to uninstall, the uninstall fails **silently**, and the user has no idea what happened or why (from a previous comment, this was fixed somewhere between 4.4.2 and 9).

Comment: OK but I see you agreed that this was already fixed, so the uninstall does not fail silently anymore.
So, you are basically looking for a solution for older android versions (can you specify for which)?

Comment: yes, basically i'm looking for a way to fix this for prior-to-official-solution versions (no idea exactly in which version this was finally addressed though).